# Xcode c++: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7)

Tags: c++, xcode

I have problem where when I try to sort a buffer I've made, I end up getting the error message: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7). I've tried but I have been unsuccessful so far with finding out where the exact problem lies and was thinking that I could need some fresh new eyes who might see what I've been missing.

the main.cpp

```
#include "int_sorted.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>

void fill(int_buffer &buffer);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int_buffer buffer(10);

    fill(buffer);
    int_sorted sort(buffer.begin(), buffer.size());
    sort.print();

    return 0;
}

void fill(int_buffer &buffer){
    int value = 0;
    for(int *i = buffer.begin(); i !=buffer.end(); i++){
        value = rand()%10;
        *i = value;
    }

    for(const int* i = buffer.begin(); i != buffer.end(); i++){
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

the buffer code.

```
#include "int_buffer.hpp"
#include <algorithm>

int_buffer::int_buffer(size_t size):buffer(new int[size]), bufferSize(size){
}

int_buffer::int_buffer(const int* source , size_t size):buffer(new int[size]), bufferSize(size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        buffer[i] = source[i];
    }
}

int_buffer::int_buffer(const int_buffer& rhs):buffer(new int[rhs.size()]), bufferSize(rhs.size()){
    std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
}

int_buffer::int_buffer(int_buffer&& rhs){
    buffer = rhs.buffer;
    bufferSize = rhs.size();
    rhs.buffer = nullptr;    
}

// ---- New edit ----   
int_buffer& int_buffer::operator=(const int_buffer& rhs){
    std::cout << "Construct copy assigned." << std::endl;
    int_buffer cpy_asgn(rhs);
    swap(cpy_asgn);
    return *this;

    /*
     if(buffer == rhs.begin()){
     return *this;
     }else if(bufferSize == rhs.size()){
     std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
     return *this;
     }else{
     delete []buffer;
     buffer = new int[rhs.size()];
     bufferSize = rhs.size();
     std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
     return *this;
     }
     */
}

int_buffer& int_buffer::operator=(int_buffer&& rhs){
    if(this != &rhs){
        delete []buffer;
        this->buffer = rhs.buffer;
        rhs.buffer = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}


size_t int_buffer::size() const{
    return bufferSize;
}

int* int_buffer::begin(){
    return buffer;
}

int* int_buffer::end(){
    return buffer + bufferSize;
}

const int* int_buffer::begin() const{
    return buffer;
}

const int* int_buffer::end() const{
    return buffer + bufferSize;
}

int_buffer::~int_buffer(){
    delete []buffer;
}
// ---- New edit ----
void int_buffer::swap(int_buffer& rhs){
    std::swap(this->buffer, rhs.buffer);
    std::swap(this->bufferSize, rhs.bufferSize);
}
```

The sort code.

```
#include "int_sorted.hpp"

int* ins_pos = nullptr;

int_sorted::int_sorted(const int* source , size_t size):buffer(source, size){
    /*if(!sort_tested()){
        *this = sort(begin(), end());
    }*/
    *this = sort(begin(), end());
}

int_sorted::int_sorted():buffer(nullptr, 0){}

size_t int_sorted::size() const{
    return buffer.size();
}

int* int_sorted::insert(int value){
    int_buffer buffer(&value, 1);
    if(!sort_tested()){
        sort(begin(), end());
    }
    *this = merge(int_sorted(buffer.begin(), 1));
    return ins_pos;
}

const int* int_sorted::begin() const{
    return buffer.begin();
}
const int* int_sorted::end() const{
    return buffer.end();
}

bool int_sorted::sort_tested(){
    int* a = buffer.end();
    int* b = nullptr;

    while(a != buffer.end()){
        b = a + 1;
        if(b == buffer.end()){
            return true;
        }
        if(*a > *b){
            return false;
        }
        a = b;
    }
    return true;
}

int_sorted int_sorted::merge(const int_sorted& merge_with) const{

    int_buffer tempBuffer(buffer.size() + merge_with.size());

    const int* x = buffer.begin();
    const int* y = merge_with.begin();
    int* z = tempBuffer.begin();

    while(x != buffer.end() && y != merge_with.end()){
        if(*x < *y){
            *z = *x;
            x++;
        }else{
            *z = *y;
            y++;
            if(merge_with.size() == 1){
                ins_pos = z;
            }
        }
        z++;
    }
    while(x != buffer.end()){
        *z = *x;
        x++;
        z++;
    }
    while(y != merge_with.end()){
        *z = *y;
        y++;
        z++;
        if(merge_with.size() == 1){
            ins_pos = z;
        }
    }

    return int_sorted(tempBuffer.begin(), tempBuffer.size());
}

int_sorted int_sorted::sort(const int* begin , const int* end){

    if ( begin == end )
        return int_sorted();

    if ( begin == end - 1 )
        return int_sorted(begin, 1);

    ptrdiff_t half = ( end-begin )/2; // pointer diff type
    const int* mid = begin + half;
    return sort(begin , mid).merge(sort(mid, end));
}

void int_sorted::print(){
    for(auto i = buffer.begin(); i != buffer.end(); i++)
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
}
```

the buffer header.

```
#ifndef int_buffer_hpp
#define int_buffer_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class int_buffer{
 public:
    explicit int_buffer(size_t size); // size_t is defined in cstdlib

    int_buffer(const int* source , size_t size);

    int_buffer(const int_buffer& rhs); // copy construct

    int_buffer(int_buffer&& rhs); // move construct

    int_buffer & operator=(const int_buffer& rhs); // copy assign

    int_buffer & operator=(int_buffer&& rhs); // move assign

    size_t size() const;

    int* begin();
    int* end();
    const int* begin() const;
    const int* end() const;
    ~int_buffer();
private:
    // ---- New edit ----
    void swap(int_buffer& rhs);
    int* buffer;
    size_t bufferSize;
};

#endif /* int_buffer_hpp */
```

The sort header.

```
#ifndef int_sorted_hpp
#define int_sorted_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "int_buffer.hpp"

class int_sorted{
  public:
    int_sorted(const int* source , size_t size);
    int_sorted();
    size_t size() const;
    int* insert(int value); // returns the insertion point.
    const int* begin() const;
    const int* end() const;
    bool sort_tested();
    int_sorted merge(const int_sorted& merge_with) const;
    int_sorted sort(const int* begin , const int* end);
    void print();
  private:
    int_buffer buffer;
};


#endif /* int_sorted_hpp */
```

Comment: Why not simply use `std::vector<int>` instead of `int_buffer`?

Comment: It's a learning exercise to familiarize myself with RAII and the buffer works reasonably well so far, it's the sort that is making a fuss at the moment. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Your assignment operator has holes in it.  If `new[]` throws an exception, you've corrupted your data.  Look at the [copy/swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) to see how to write an assignment operator that doesn't have this flaw.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to see if there's change. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, if you used the mergesort code [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c/24650627) on your `int_buffer` class, you will see that it sorts correctly.  Why are you even creating such a class called `int_sorted` anyway?  The issue has little to do with RAII, and everything to do with implementing a class that need not be implemented (`int_sorted`).  The `int_buffer` on the surface seems to be working (with the issue I pointed out with the assignment operator).

Comment: [Online example](https://www.ideone.com/FN6x47).  Honestly, it makes more sense to implement a generic merge sort and then test your buffer on that, rather than creating a class called `int_sort`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hi, sorry for the long response time, I've made the changes as you suggested and I still have the same problem. I think it might have to do with the sort function in the sort.cpp file but I'm still not sure. The reason why I'm not using the std::sort has to do with the exercise as well. the new edits have been marked with ---- New edit ---- for easier visibility.

Comment: Look again.  The merge sort I linked to also does not use `std::sort`.  What you're implementing for sorting is very confusing -- there is no need for a separate `int_buffer` class for sorting.  Just write your version of merge sort using iterators, and pass your `int_buffer.begin()` and `int_buffer.end()` pointers to it.  If you need to write a class, then wrap up the interface in a class, but behind the scenes, you call the internal merge sort code.  The way you've implemented your sort is again, very confusing and not surprising it has issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184704/discussion-between-user2125673-and-paulmckenzie).